# Analytics on a web application

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics

We have an web application. Part of web the application is profiles. Profiles have following urls:

/Profile/1
/Profile/2
/Profile/3

We also have Adds. Add's urls are as following:
/Add/1
/Add/2
/Add/3

I need a view of top 20 most viewed profiles and top 20 most viewed add's and how many views they have. It must also be possible to extract those two lists with c#. Can this be achieved with log analytics? Do you need to extract everything your self from application insights and do analytics your self, or how would you achieve this?

---

I made a little POC. I have added following to AI. The https://gac/url/1 has thousands of id's. Maybe there us 244 views on https://gac/url/1 and 1128 views on https://gac/url/2and so forth.

[image]
I noticed that Id is not added to the log. See code below:

```
 public void WritePageView(string name, string id, Uri url)
 {
     var pageView = new PageViewTelemetry
     {
          Name = name,
          Id = id,
          Url = url
     };

     pageView.Properties.Add("Id", "1");    
     telemetry.TrackPageView(pageView);
}
```

What I need is a top 20 (top x) of which https://gac/url is most visited. Something like:

https://gac/url1: 3434
https://gac/url1: 2432
https://gac/url1: 1298
https://gac/url1: 8211
..
If showed in a graph to would be really great.

So it would be something like group by name and Id. But as Id is only pressent in the url how do I extract that?

Comment: All these logs are in PageViews table of application insights log analytics, it should be easy to write query for your purpose.

Comment: you say "id is not added to the log", but I see it in the `customDimensions` column.  is that not the thing you're talking about?  for that, you'd use `extend id = tostring(customDimensions.Id)` to your query to get items out of customDimensions

Comment: Is it a typo in your post? I see they're all https://gac/url1 in this sentence: https://gac/url1: 3434 https://gac/url1: 2432 https://gac/url1: 1298 https://gac/url1: 8211 .. If showed in a graph to would be really great.

Comment: Yes type. It is not production but a environment I created for to demo the goal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to use analytics query for application insights.

Nav to your azure portal -> application insights -> Logs(Analytics), the related info should be in the **pageViews** table. When you write your query, you can set custom "Time Range" via UI or use where clause.

You can get all the pageViews info by just write "pageViews", screenshot as below:

[image]

And you can use [Summarize operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/summarizeoperator) and [count operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/query/countoperator) to get the total views count for each page. Sample query code like below:

```
pageViews 
| summarize totalCount = count(url) by url
| order by totalCount desc
```

The result as below:

[image]

If you want to only get the top 2 most views page, use the following code:

```
pageViews 
| summarize totalCount = count(url) by url
| order by totalCount desc
| top 2 by totalCount
```

Comment: Thanks appreciated. Is there anyway to extract the parameter and use that. Lets say we have /Profile/1, /Profile/1, /Profile/2,/Profile/3,/Profile/3, /Profile/3, /Profile/3 I would like to show there in a graph that Profile1 is showed two times ... ? So list of most viewed profiles.

Comment: @ThomasSegato Are these things like /Profile/1, /Profile/2 are urls? and show them in a graph with visited number? It's better if you can provide a screenshot of your query result.

Comment: I havent created anything yet, making a strategy for how to di the analytics. All of those are Urls. Let me make a small pilot and get pack.. Thanks.